# Reset child widget from parent widget in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a child widget that is full of variables. When I do a setState() on my parent widget, I want it to refresh the child widget so that all of the variables inside the child widget and reinstantiated. Here's essentially what I mean.

The parent widget:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
     body: Column(
           children =[
                   ChildWidget(addAmount: addAmount),
                   RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Reset Parent'),
                    onPressed: () => setState(){},
           ]
           ),
  );
}
```

And here's the child

```
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final addAmount;
  ChildWidget({this.addAmount});

  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {

  int counter = 0;
  
  increaseCounter() {
     counter = counter + widget.addAmount;
  }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
         children:[
           RaisedButton(
                   child: Text('Add to counter'),
                   onPressed: () {
                       increaseCounter();
                       setState((){});
                      },
           ),
           Text($counter),
          ]
   );
}
}
```

So essentially, when I press the Reset Parent button, I want to be able to set the counter in the ChildWidget to zero again. But it doesn't reset to 0, it retains the number that it has been adding up. How do I reset the ChildWidget's variables from the parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `didUpdateWidget`:

```
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final addAmount;
  ChildWidget({this.addAmount});

  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {

  int counter = 0;

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant S oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    counter = 0;
  }
  
  increaseCounter() {
     counter = counter + widget.addAmount;
  }

  return Column(
         children:[
           RaisedButton(
                   child: Text('Add to counter'),
                   onPressed: () {
                       increaseCounter();
                      },
           ),
           Text($counter),
          ]
   );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I left out the Widget build(BuildContext context) {... line in my question. Would that affect your solution? You can see my corrected child widget in the original question